# Getting message after server starts 'C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa, ehcache, c3p0

I'm working on Spring, Spring MVC, JPA with hibernate, c3p0, MySql and also configuring second level caching in it 'EhCache' but I'm getting following message continuously.

```
`15:33:30.905 [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2sa2hm9cjo7aj41i6px5b|7a7887a9]-AdminTaskTimer] DEBUG c.m.v.a.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@2e2e71ba -- Running DeadlockDetector[Exiting. No pending tasks.]
```

15:33:32.817 [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2sa2hm9cjo7aj41i6px5b|4c9525c4]-AdminTaskTimer] DEBUG c.m.v.a.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@59daacfe -- Running DeadlockDetector[Exiting. No pending tasks.]
15:33:40.905 [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2sa2hm9cjo7aj41i6px5b|7a7887a9]-AdminTaskTimer] DEBUG c.m.v.a.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@2e2e71ba -- Running DeadlockDetector[Exiting. No pending tasks.]
15:33:42.819 [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2sa2hm9cjo7aj41i6px5b|4c9525c4]-AdminTaskTimer] DEBUG c.m.v.a.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@59daacfe -- Running DeadlockDetector[Exiting. No pending tasks.]
15:33:50.910 [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2sa2hm9cjo7aj41i6px5b|7a7887a9]-AdminTaskTimer] DEBUG c.m.v.a.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@2e2e71ba -- Running DeadlockDetector[Exiting. No pending tasks.]
15:33:52.821 [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2sa2hm9cjo7aj41i6px5b|4c9525c4]-AdminTaskTimer] DEBUG c.m.v.a.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@59daacfe -- Running DeadlockDetector[Exiting. No pending tasks.]`

For this problem response is also delayed.

Answer (score 2):

You are logging c3p0 libs at too low a level. They can be very verbose at levels below `INFO`. However you are logging, set logging for `com.mchange.*` to `INFO` rather than `DEBUG`, `FINE`, `FINEST`, or `TRACE`.